# Modify Starting Slide Using localScroll jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, slider, scrollto

jQuery n00b here, I'm using the jQuery plugin scrollTo and localScroll to scroll elements in a featured area and I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify the slide I want to start with.  My 5 scrollable elements are set up in a "T" shape that has been rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise. So basically it looks like this:

1 
245 
3

```
<div id="showcase-content"> //height: 450px; width: 960px; overflow: hidden
<div id="showcase-content-wrapper"> //height: 1350px; width: 2860px; overflow: hidden
    <div class="showcase-slide" id="slideOne"> //height:450px; width: 960px; clear:both
        Slide 1
        <a class="slide2" href='#slideTwo'>down</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="showcase-slide" id="slideTwo"> //float:left
        Slide 2
        <a class="slide1" href='#slideOne'>up</a>
        <a class="slide3" href='#slideThree'>down</a>
        <a class="slide4" href='#slideFour'>right</a>
    </div>      
    <div class="showcase-slide" id="slideFour"> //float: left
        Slide 4
        <a class="slide2" href='#slideTwo'>left</a>
        <a class="slide5" href='#slideFive'>right</a>
    </div>
    <div class="showcase-slide" id="slideFive"> //float: left
        Slide 5
        <a class="slide4" href='#slideFour'>left</a>
    </div>
    <div class="showcase-slide" id="slideThree"> //clear: both
        Slide 3
        <a class="slide2" href='#slideTwo'>up</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$.localScroll({
    target: '#showcase-content', // could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
    queue:true,
    duration:1000,
    hash:false,
});
```

Currently, the slideshow begins on Slide 1, however I would like my slideshow to begin on Slide 4 and then allow users to navigate from there.  Any ideas?